# RSpec results and Rails Console behaving differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-console

Here is my `Lesson` model:

```
before_create :set_sequence

def set_sequence
  maxseq = Lesson.where(:course_id => self.course_id).maximum("sequence")
  if (maxseq.nil?)
    maxseq = 0
  end
  self.sequence = maxseq + 1
end
```

when I run `rspec` the following test fails:

```
it "validate sequence is setup" do
  lesson = Lesson.create(:title => "Testing", :description => "Testing", :course_id => 1)
  lesson.sequence.should_not eql nil
end
```

However when T test this through `rails console` the `Lesson` object is created successfully and with the correct sequence. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

`lesson.sequence.should_not be_nil` is the correct way to test for nil, as far as I know. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Any validations you've got on Lesson could be silently aborting the create before your callback gets called.  Change it to `create!` in the spec to check it.

Comment: i checked there are no validation errors. the Lesson object does get created but somehow sequence attribute isn't getting set.

Comment: Do you know for sure that set_sequence is getting called?

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryGirl` first initializes object with no parameters, and then assigns parameters one by one. The callback in your model probably would not work in this case. So you can try to change `FactoryGirl`'s behavior by adding

```
initialize_with { new(attributes) }
```

to the `Lesson`'s factory. I'm not sure it will help though. Testing callback behavior in Rails is tricky.